# what is named groups (starting with a colon and ending with a star ) in angular path?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in one of angular developer code it is mentioned like:

```
.when('/home/dev/:angular*\/edit', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/subject-header',
        controller: 'SubjectCtrl'
      })
```

what does `:angular*\`  mean? in [angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) developer guide it is called as named group of path. i have google searched but didn't get appropriate answer.please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All characters are eagerly stored in $routeParams under the given `angular` when the route matches.

For example, routes like

```
/home/dev/:angular*\/edit
```

will match

```
/home/dev/these/will/be/included/edit
```

What you get:

```
angular : these/will/be/included
```